# Rendering problems in Safari 11.1 in Mac OS 10.13

Tags: macos, mac, safari

I faced with strange rendering problems when use Safari in my iMac: sometimes after I search in Google using address bar, page not rendered and text in address bar disappears (see attached screenshots).

[image]

And sometimes text in address bar became invisible

[image]

In Chrome everything is fine.

I already tried disable extensions/reset cache/reset settings, but nothing helps.

Does anyone has experience with such problems?
I tried search other people with such problem, but didn't find anything in Google

Comment: I have the same problem!!
safari only renders an small search bar

Comment: Do you have any system or Safari updates available? I would advise you install any macOS updates as they not only include Safari updates and fixes, but will also clear some caches on your system.

Comment: @Jake3231 I always install latest updates as soon as they appears. It started to happens few month ago. That's why I wondering is anybody has the same problem...

Comment: Same issues on Safari Version 11.1 (13605.1.33.1.2) on a mac pro 5,1 running 10.13.4 (the latest). Started the minute Safari was "upgraded" to 11.1.Getting a blank page on many key websites I use daily. Did not upgrade my laptop, which is still running 10.13, and Safari 11.0, and all those websites working normally there. Thank heavens! Quite a pain to have to leave the home comforts of Safari to use Firefox and other browsers on my main machine.